# Flooded requests in apache access log from unknown urls

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, apache2, ddos

My Apache access logs on AWS are flooded with unknown requests. What is the way out of it? I have tried to create new instance with the old image and the problem persists.

Snippet of access log below :

```
    27.219.140.6:80 - - [16/Dec/2015:12:16:34] "GET http://ib.adnxs.com/ttj?id=2502016&referrer=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gamesindustry.biz%2F&cb=94400 HTTP/1.0" 302 871 "http://www.gamesindustry.biz/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; FunWebProducts; GTB6.5; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; eSobiSubscriber 2.0.4.16; OfficeLiveConnector.1.5; OfficeLivePatch." 0
    212.253.110.157:80 - - [16/Dec/2015:12:16:35] "GET http://www.apple.com/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5190 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0; WOW64; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; Media Center PC 5.0; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)" 0
    41.142.156.138:80 - - [16/Dec/2015:12:16:36] "GET http://www.msftncsi.com/ncsi.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 210 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0; WOW64; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; Media Center PC 5.0; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)" 0
    142.54.163.44:80 - - [16/Dec/2015:12:16:36] "GET http://n204adserv.com/ads-sync.js?v=1&key=75c9de7c92b8d52328ebd5ae841ecff4&cIds=&adsCampaignKey=0&ch=window.location.hostname.replace(/[^w.-_~]/g, HTTP/1.0" 200 1727 "http://www.cyclingnews.com" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; GTB6; Acoo Browser; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)" 0
```

Getting flooded from these unknown domains. This is making the server completely unusable. Any pointers on this?

Comment: Are you just accepting connections directly on an EC2 instance, or are you using other services like an ELB, CloudFront, etc.?  I seem to recall running into a similar problem a year or so ago caused by an ELB.  I forget if we launched a new ELB or not.  I think we contacted AWS Support after we started seeing this and they ultimately patched/fixed the ELB's to make it stop happening.

Comment: Accepting connections directly on EC2 instance using route 53

Comment: If you have an AWS support plan then I'd still recommend contacting them about this.  This behavior looks very familiar to me, although from long ago.  It's possible one or more of their ELB's (which is a shared resource as I understand) may be incorrectly directing traffic to your EC2 instance.

Comment: It look like you have misconfigured your web server as an open proxy and someone has discovered that fact and people are now surfing the web through you.  This server should be taken offline until you find and correct the error.  You are paying for this bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

As Michael - sqlbot said, looks like your instance is acting as an open proxy.

You can check if this is true by using an online proxy tester such as http://www.proxy-checker.org/ enter the servers outward facing IP address and try with port 80 and 8080 and see if it reports if it is open.

If it is, check your apache site configurations and apache modules, do you need mod_proxy enabled? etc.